# How to setup the redirect url from Homestead using Socialite with Google?

Tags: laravel, homestead, google-signin, laravel-socialite

When you try to setup Socialite for Laravel, using Homestead (here on Ubuntu), the "redirect url" needed for Google Sign-In are always marked as 'bad' :

```
Error: invalid_request

Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: https://homestead.test/google/callback
```

And trying to add `http://homestead.test/google/callback` or `http://192.168.10.10/google/callback` end up either as a :

```
"Non top level domain supported"
```

or just with

```
"Non valid URI"
```

Is it hopeless due to Google restrictions or is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah found ! Short answer :

Edit your /etc/hosts with a real tld domain that you bypass :

```
192.168.10.10   example.com
```

And then tell Google to accept it :

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=xxx
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=xxx

Comment: Seems as though you have to be a G Suite user to do this